# How `fff` fake function framework avoids breaking ODR rule while introducing stong symbols?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I am trying to wrap my head about `fff` framework and the one definition rule of C++.

I use `fff` to mock free functions and test them, I will use the following example to explain what the question.

The library to be mocked is `libarchive` and I mock `archive_write_free`.

I have the following set of files:

1. `LibArchiveFake.h` -> It contains the declaration `DECLARE_FAKE_VALUE_FUNC`
2. `LibArchiveFake.cpp` -> It contains the definition `DEFINE_FAKE_VALUE_FUNC` and compiles to an object file.
3. `TarballArchiverTest.cpp` -> Which includes the header file and contains the actual test, and also compiles to an object file.
4. `tar_test` which is simply the binary.

The binary is compiled with the previously mentioned object files and links against `libarchive.so` as following.

```
g++  -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic -g -ggdb -O0 -DNC_DEBUG CMakeFiles/utilitiesTests.dir/mainTest.cpp.o CMakeFiles/utilitiesTests.dir/FStreamFilesystemOpsTest.cpp.o CMakeFiles/utilitiesTests.dir/CopierTest.cpp.o CMakeFiles/utilitiesTests.dir/FakeLibArchive.cpp.o CMakeFiles/utilitiesTests.dir/TarballArchiverTest.cpp.o -o utilitiesTests -lgmock /usr/lib64/libgtest.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.74.0 /usr/local/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.74.0 /usr/lib64/libarchive.so /usr/lib64/libgtest.so -lpthread
```

I checked the generated object file of `LibArchiveFake.cpp` via readelf and its `.ii` file. It contains a strong definition of `archive_write_free`, also `/usr/lib64/libarchive.so` does.

`LibArchiveFake.o` : `55: 000000000000275f   752 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 archive_write_free`

`/usr/lib64/libarchive.so.o` : `572: 0000000000063740     9 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 archive_write_free`

I know there are some exceptions to the ODR, yet I don't understand how `fff` doesn't break the ODR.

I will appreciate any clues.

Comment: What kind of file is `/usr/lib64/libarchive.so.o`? If this a typo? If so please update your
post to include instead the actual output of your `readelf` commands unedited, except perhaps by cutting irrelevant lines.

Answer (score 0):

It violates the ODR and the behaviour of programs that use this utility are not specified by the C++ standard.

In this case, the specifics of how the linker works with symbol loading from so files happens to make the result not completely disasterous.